# Heap keeps increasing in Google Map API V2

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, heap-memory

I have got a problem which is driving me wild. I used Google Map API V2 in my Code and when I'm moving the map I can see the following Logcat output (on Nexus 7):

```
01-23 21:17:10.724: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4531K, 21% free 12911K/16312K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
01-23 21:17:10.724: I/dalvikvm-heap(5484): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.043MB for 285724-byte allocation
01-23 21:17:10.744: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 200K, 22% free 12990K/16592K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
01-23 21:17:12.074: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1326K, 23% free 12893K/16592K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
01-23 21:18:04.854: D/dalvikvm(5484): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-23 21:18:07.374: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 658K, 23% free 12904K/16592K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
01-23 21:18:07.384: I/dalvikvm-heap(5484): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.763MB for 1048592-byte allocation
01-23 21:18:07.404: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 21% free 13925K/17620K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
01-23 21:18:07.714: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2127K, 26% free 13054K/17620K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
01-23 21:18:44.694: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1894K, 27% free 12970K/17620K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 56ms
01-23 21:18:46.684: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1738K, 27% free 12996K/17620K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 53ms
01-23 21:18:49.254: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1756K, 27% free 13014K/17620K, paused 2ms+8ms, total 77ms
01-23 21:18:56.864: I/dalvikvm(5484): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
01-23 21:18:56.934: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1840K, 21% free 13010K/16312K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 49ms
01-23 21:18:59.434: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1779K, 21% free 12995K/16312K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 50ms
01-23 21:19:03.414: D/dalvikvm(5484): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1781K, 21% free 13007K/16312K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 48ms
```

The heap keeps growing and growing and I have no idea what I can do about it. I searched through the web and through stackoverflow, but there was no helpful answer for me.
I hope someone of you can find the error. I am very new to Android, so please appreciate.

EDIT1: Heap Dump:

[image: Here you can see what causes the heap allocation.]

EDIT2: MAT Analysis

Suspect 1:

```
One instance of "maps.by.a" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4480cfa8" occupies 1.002.352 (22,33%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "maps.by.d" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4480cfa8".

Keywords
maps.by.a
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4480cfa8
maps.by.d
```

Suspect 2:

```
3.507 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 795.104 (17,72%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:
•class com.ibm.icu4jni.util.Resources$DefaultTimeZones @ 0x401fccc8 - 151.744 (3,38%) bytes. 
•class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0x4016d288 - 126.592 (2,82%) bytes. 
•class org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services @ 0x40091188 - 51.456 (1,15%) bytes. 


Keywords
java.lang.Class
```

Suspect 3:

```
8.168 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 529.048 (11,79%) bytes. 

Keywords
java.lang.String
```

Comment: When you examined a DDMS heap dump in MAT, what did you find was taking up the memory?

Comment: Um, while that's an interesting table, that's only marginally useful to you. You may wish to read [this Android Developers Blog post about using MAT](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html), or watch [this Google I|O 2011 presentation on the use of MAT and related tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk), to learn more about how to find memory leaks with MAT.

Comment: Ok tried it today. You can look at EDIT2. Please help me identifying the memory leak, because I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your heap doesn't "keep growing". It is hovering between 12893K and 13054K, rising and falling, with one outlier peak at 13925K. Personally, I don't see anything in that log that would worry me.

Regarding your MAT output, if those are the three top culprits, none are surprising. The latter two say "I am writing an app for Android", as those are always there on any Android app. The first one indicates that Maps V2 has one rather pudgy object. Again, I see nothing in that output that would suggest a problem.

Comment: Nothing to worry about? Should I ignore these heap growths?

Comment: @MichaelEder: Your heap will naturally grow as your app gets used, up to the per-process heap limit of the device. If you run out of heap, *then* you have a problem. You are welcome to worry now if you want, but since you are "new to Android", you probably have far bigger fish to fry and a lot more experience to gain before you will understand what is and is not a memory leak. Tracking down memory leaks is tricky business (I have a whole chapter on MAT in my book) and not something people generally worry about until they get a lot closer to heap limits.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will ignore the "leak" until I gain more experience in Android.

Comment: It sounds like there is a memory issue with the new API.  Google confirmed: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766.  Similar dumps are found if you poke around some other projects like their MyTracks app: http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/issues/detail?id=1210 and also https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/GQ98FFArobU

Comment: @Steven: Oh, it is eminently possible that there is a problem. I just got another report this morning about `setRetainInstance(true)` on the `MapFragment` being a possible source of leaks. However, the details on this specific question would not necessarily lead one to think that this specific app is suffering from a leak.

Comment: @CommonsWare  would you mind have a look at my question, it is similar but use much more memory, Thanks in advance. the link is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409009/gc-for-alloc-for-android-google-maps-api-v2-initialization